# help with writing a dired function to convert md to org with pandoc CLI..started but stuck

Tags: dired, functions

im trying to write a function that will be used in dired where i would launch it on the file at point and it will convert it using pandoc. i have the following code chunk (warning: my coding skills are basiclly zero :))

```
 (defun  z/dired-shell-md2org ()
 ""
 (interactive)
 (shell-command (concat "pandoc -o OUTPUT.org" (dired-file-name-at-point))))
```

the original pandoc command i use succesfuly is this

```
pandoc -o EDA.org EDA.md
```

can anyone guide me on 2 things:

1. how does one get the current file variable (i think its `dired-file-name-at-point`) to be the last word
2. is there a way that instead of OUTPUT.org it will use the same filename (sans extension) of original file at point?

Basically i want the converted orf file to have the same name as the original md file

Comment: You should insert a space at the end of the string `"pandoc -o OUTPUT.org"` to separate the file names in the shell command. If you use `shell-command` you should also use quotes around file names, i.e. `"\"...\""`. Furthermore, `file-name-sans-extension` is your friend and look up the `format` function in the emacs-lisp help.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want something like `(format "pandoc -o %s.org" (file-name-base (dired-get-filename)))` instead of `(concat...)`. You can use `dired-file-name-at-point` if you want to, but that requires point to actually be on the file name, and not just somewhere on the same line.  E.g. (untested):

```el
(defun  z/dired-shell-md2org ()
 "..."
 (interactive)
 (let ((base  (file-name-base (dired-get-filename))))
   (shell-command (format "pandoc -o %s.org %.md" base base))))
```

Or this (to automatically quote file names for shell etc.):

```el
(require 'dired-aux)

(defun  z/dired-shell-md2org ()
  "..."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((file  (dired-get-filename))
         (base  (file-name-base file)))
    (unless (string= ".md" (file-name-extension file :PERIOD))
      (error "File is not an MD file"))
    (dired-run-shell-command
      (dired-shell-stuff-it "pandoc -o "
                            (list (format " %s.org" base) (format " %s.md" base))
                            nil))))
```

Comment: thx drew! when i run this while point is on a md file (index.md) i get this error: `file-name-base: Symbol's function definition is void: dired-get-file-name`